# adding points per pixel along some axis for 2D polygon

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming I have an open polygon represented by a list of 2D points. E.g. the representation of some kind of a triangle-polygon without a basis would be:

```
import numpy as np
polygon_arr = np.array([[0,0], [15,10], [2,4]])
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to enrich the representation, i.e. adding points to the *polygon_arr* such that the polygon itself wouldn't change but for every y value (in the range of the polygon) there would be a matching point in the *polygon_arr*.

Example:

```
simple_line_polygon = np.array([[0,0], [10,5]])
enriched_representation = foo(simple_line_polygon)
# foo() should return: np.array([[0,0], [2,1], [4,2], [6,3], [8,4], [10,5]])
```

I thought of considering each two adjacent points in the polygon, construct a line equation (y=mx+n) and sample it for each y within the range; then treat special cases such as two points are vertical (so the line equation is not defined) and the case where the points are already closer to each other than one-pixel change in y value. However, this is not so elegant and would appreciate better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a line equation here. You can just scale the x and y distances between points separately. If there should be a minimum distance between the points, you can check that by computing the Euclidean distance between corners. Here is a small function that hopefully does what you are after:

```
import numpy as np

def enrich_polygon(polygon, maxpoints = 5, mindist=1):

    result = []

    ##looping over all lines of the polygon:
    for start, end in zip(polygon, np.vstack([polygon[1:],polygon[:1]])):
        dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((start-end)**2)) ##distance between points
        N = int(min(maxpoints+1,dist/mindist)) ##amount of sub-sections
        if N < 2:                              ##mindist already reached
            result += [start]

        ##generating the new points:
        ##put all points (including original start) on the line into results 
        else:
            result += [
                start+i*(end-start)/(N-1) for i in range(N-1)
            ]
    return np.array(result)

polygon_arr = np.array([[0,0], [15,10], [2,4]])
res = enrich_polygon(polygon_arr)

print(res)
```

The function takes the original polygon and iterates over pairs of neighbouring corner points. If the distance between two corners is larger than `mindist`, new points will be added up to maxpoints (the maximum amount of points to be added per line). For the given example the result looks like this:

```
[[ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 3.          2.        ]
 [ 6.          4.        ]
 [ 9.          6.        ]
 [12.          8.        ]
 [15.         10.        ]
 [12.4         8.8       ]
 [ 9.8         7.6       ]
 [ 7.2         6.4       ]
 [ 4.6         5.2       ]
 [ 2.          4.        ]
 [ 1.33333333  2.66666667]
 [ 0.66666667  1.33333333]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me the idea I was missing with working with vecrtors rather than line equations